# The image from finite set is finite / Axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
**Definitions**:
$|A| \le |B|$ if there is an injection from $A$ into $B$;
$|A| \ge |B|$ if there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$;
$|A| = |B|$ if there is a bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

**Theorem 1**:
Assuming AC, for any set $A$ and $B$, $|A| \ge |B| \Rightarrow |B| \le |A|$.

I am trying to show the following:
**Claim**:
For each nonempty set $X$ and any function $f: X \to Y$, if $A$ is a subset of $X$,
$$
|A| < |\N| \Rightarrow |f[A]| < |\N|
$$
That is, the image of a finite set is finite.

**Attempt**:
Assume $|A| < |\N|$. Since $f$ is a function, $f|_A\to {f[A]}$ is a surjection, that is, $|A| \ge |f[A]|$.

1. By Theorem 1, we have $|f[A]| \le |A|$. Because the composition of injections is an injection, $|f[A]| \le |A| \le |\N|$.
2. Now, suppose that $|f[A]| = |\N|$ aiming for contradiction. Since the composition of a bijection and surjection is a surjection, $|A| \ge |f[A]| \ge |\N|$. Hence, by Theorem 1, we have $|\N| \le |A|$, and by Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, $|A| = |\N|$, which is a contradiction.

Finally, $|f[A]| \le |\N| \land |f[A]| \neq |\N|$.

**Questions**:

1. Is this valid proof?
2. Do I really need AC to prove the proposition? Since I am dealing with finite sets, it seems that invoking AC is overkill.

This question is continued in [Hermis14](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4368650/334795).

Thank you.

Comment: Using $\leq$ and $\geq$ is $\large\textbf{AWEFUL}$. There is a notation for the existence of surjections, that is $\leq^*$.

Comment: Overkill.... Probably.  But otherwise we need to prove a modified version that if $A$ is finite and $|A|\ge |B|$ then $|B|\le |A|$, which I believe *is* provable and not axiomatic (as opposed to AC).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the advice. Though I was also uncomfortable when I saw the notation for the first time, I have no choice because Folland, the author of the book I am reading, is using the notations. In fact, I am now accustomed to it and don't feel bad about it.

Comment: No no, you *should* feel bad about it. Just because you're learning something which is absolutely terrible doesn't mean you need to get used to it. If tomorrow morning I'll write a book and define a compact space as "every two points can be separated by disjoint open sets", it won't be reasonable either.

Comment: @fleablood Yes. Showing the proposition is indeed sufficient for this question. Finiteness is defined such that there is an injection but no bijection onto $\mathbb{N}$, which is a tricky condition. I am struggling with it.

Comment: @Hermis14 again well-orderability is your friend. If something injects into $\mathbb N$, any such injection induces a well-ordering.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That is indeed a key idea I need right now, by which I can always choose the minimum, right? Could you tell me the reliable reference for the statement?

Comment: @Hermis Let $f:A\to \mathbb N$ injective. Choose the element of $A$ such that $f(a)$ is least. (This well-defined / unique since f is injective.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I really appreciate your help. Would you check my updated post? It has the lemma appended at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I don’t think you used any invalid reasoning in the proof, but as you suspect, it is overkill for the finite case and no AC is necessary. Actually, it is not required in the more general circumstance where $A$ is well-orderable, since you can choose the least preimage of each point in $f(A)$ according to some well-ordering of $A$ to get an injective mapping $f(A)\to A.$

Comment: I really appreciate your confirmation. But do you have time to make a more concrete hint for a proof without AC? :)

Comment: The hint is right there in the answer: choose a (well-)ordering of $A$.

Comment: @Hermis14. The last part of my answer was intended as such. You need an injection $f(A)\to A$ and you can get that without AC if $A$ is well-orderable. And finite sets are well-orderable.

Comment: @Hermis14 If that still doesn’t make sense, I would suggest reviewing how the proof of the general statement (using AC) works and see how a well-ordering of A removes the need for arbitrary choices of preimages. (And that finite sets are well-orderable is either part of the definition or an immediate consequence, depending on the definition of finite. E.g. a finite set can be put into one-to-one correspondence with a natural number, so inherits a well ordering.)